# Empty or null array value not filter or remove from array list

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I 
I have tried to remove null or empty values from array listing but not working.

Following is my array output..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1173
            [post_content] => Rocking Tips
            [comment_id] => 1173
            [comment_content] => Nice Post 
            [comment_date] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [email] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 
            [post_content] => 
            [comment_id] => 
            [comment_content] => 
            [comment_date] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [username] => 
            [email] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1173
            [post_content] => Rocking Tips
            [comment_id] => 1176
            [comment_content] => WOnder
            [comment_date] => 2020-05-21 21:10:04
            [user_id] => 168
            [username] => kkkk20
            [email] => fdfsfsf@gmail.com
            [first_name] => sam
            [last_name] => test

            [reply] => Array
                (
                    [comment_id] => 1177
                    [comment_details] => Thank YOu
                    [comment_date] => 2020-05-21 21:12:14
                    [user_id] => 179

                    [username] => test20201
                    [email] => fdfdfd@gmail.com
                    [replay] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried to remove empty array value using **array_filter()** but still empty value is showing when i print my array.

I also tried like,

```
$filtered = array_filter($myArray, function($var){return !is_null($var);} );
echo "<pre>List Data";print_r($filtered);
```

I want to remove `1` index array from list

Answer (score 2):

An array whose values are empty strings is not the same as `NULL`. You need to test the values.

You can call `array_filter()` on the element. This will return all the non-empty values in the array; if all the values are empty it will return an empty array, which will be condidered falsey by the outer `array_filter()`.

```
$filtered = array_filter($myArray, function($var){return array_filter($var);} );
```

Or you could just check whether a specific element such as `post_id` is empty:

```
$filtered = array_filter($myArray, function($var){return !empty($var['post_id']);} );
```